# Make wipe diagonal transition after first video ends?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editor, transitions

[How to create “diagonal wipe” effect in FFmpeg?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/24608/how-to-create-diagonal-wipe-effect-in-ffmpeg/24616#24616?newreg=1c0bdf6bd6ec4e4ea14dec86fcc2a93c)

After looking at the answer of this question, I am wondering how can I make the transition to happen between the finish of the first one and the start of the second one (in the middle of the two).

Comment: I added a new answer to the question you linked to. It allows you to easily set the timing of the transition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create “diagonal wipe” effect in FFmpeg?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/24608/how-to-create-diagonal-wipe-effect-in-ffmpeg)